# Nhibernate - item gets its ParentID updated to null instead of being deleted

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

The business logic inside a process is:

- begin transaction
- add an item to a collection
- perform a find("somethingA")
- delete that item depending on the previous step.
- commit transaction

Im using cascade all-delete-orphans, and the inverse=true, both in my parent class. When removing the item from the collection, I set the `.parentObj = null` and remove the item from the collection.

When using `TemplateFlushMode.Auto`, I profiled the Database and the following is done:

- INSERT item
- SELECT related tosomethingA
- UPDATE parentID (the FK to the parent) of the Item to NULL

(the insert item is done because a `find()` is done, to guarantee data consistency in the database). The the select is done, and then I would expect a `DELETE` to be performed... but an update to `parentID = null` is done.

When performing a `Session.Flush()` right before the `Find()`, the following happens:

- INSERT item
- SELECT related tosomethingA
- DELETE Item

When using `TemplateFlushMode.Commit`, the changes are done at the end of the transaction and the item is never inserted:

- SELECT related tosomethingA

The app I'm working with is using `TemplateFlushMode.Auto`, so I'm wondering, ,is there an explanation why the cascading is not working if a select is done in between one item is added and then removed in the same transaction?

I know the first answer that comes up is "don't add an item to a collection, if it will be removed afterwards". But I rather don't change the business logic.

Does anyone know why an update is being done instead of a `delete` when using `AUTO`? (when using `Commit` it does not insert the object)

Comment: Hey Adrián, good question, I have the same question as you actually.

Comment: Can I ask what are you trying to accomplish with this? it may be a different solution.

Comment: This is a common ORM issue, and NH handles it via a combination of relational, cascade and null directives. As @giammin says, it would best if you posted your mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use the `cascade="delete"` option in your mapping file in order to cascade on delete

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a two way one to many binding ? Have you marked `not-null="true"` on the foreign key in the `details` table ? Can you please post your mappings XML file for better understanding ?

I know that i haven't answered your question, but I do not have enough reputation to post a comment instead.